# How to fix "ill-formed xml" error while submitting feed to Amazon MWS?

Tags: java, xml, sdk, integration, amazon-mws

I'm trying to send feed of type _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ but getting error

```
<ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
<ResultMessageCode>50001</ResultMessageCode>
<ResultDescription>The XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 3, column 18.</ResultDescription>
```

That's what i'm sending

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Header>
        <documentVersion>1.01</documentVersion>
        <merchantIdentifier>A4DPWIBKRJAR</merchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <Message>
        <messageID>9c23467c-c3da-4afb-b141-379d87c960cb</messageID>
        <orderFulfillment>
            <amazonOrderID>123123123</amazonOrderID>
            <fulfillmentDate>2019-08-05</fulfillmentDate>
            <fulfillmentData>
                <carrierCode>USPS</carrierCode>
                <shipperTrackingNumber>123123123</shipperTrackingNumber>
            </fulfillmentData>
            <item>
                <amazonOrderItemCode>123123123</amazonOrderItemCode>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </orderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

It looks same to what is provided in this example https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html?itemID=200387170&

There is similar post but I tried to send this xml without any formatting with no success
[XML Error: Ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341287/xml-error-ill-formed-at-the-amazon-envelope-xml-level)

Comment: I checked the XML provided, and it is a well-formed XML. On the other hand, Amazon XML shall be valid against XML Schema. It seems that you need to validate the XML against some Amazon XML Schema for a particular data feed.

Comment: Hi @Mikita, i know this is an off topic but I need your help, can you plese take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389290/amazon-developer-id